# About the usage of "an" in this context

Tags: articles, indefinite-articles

To believe a person is not necessarily to treat him as an original
authority. He is ***an*** original authority on what he himself has done
and seen and heard: I say an original authority because I only mean
that he does himself contribute something, e.g. is in some sort a witness, as opposed to one who only transmits information received. ... Thus a speaker may be a **total original authority** for the fact
that he gives, as would usually be the case if one of us said he had
eaten an apple, or **an original authority, but not a total one**, as if he
says he saw some of Leonardo’s drawings; or he may not be an original authority at all, as if he says that Leonardo made drawings for a
flying machine.

Is there a special usage of "an" at work here? Does it mean something like "not fully"?

Answer (score 1):

"An"  or 'a' indicating one of many, or an example of a type.

I am eating an apple.  I am taking a test.

So the author is saying this person has an opinion but it is nothing special.